# Elastic search: Mapping and query to match omitted letters in word

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, wildcard

I have an existing ElasticSearch index and mapped collection of documents.

I am using ElasticSearch version 8.6

I have a document with a title field of "helloo".  I need to return this document from a query for "hello" (missing the final letter o).  I don't want to return documents with a word after the query word (so don't return "hello there").

What is the best field type and query to achieve this?  Would a wildcard field work and, if so, how would I form the query?